# SWIG - Mapping C++ shift right and shift left operators

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ DLL for which I am trying to build a SWIG interface file.  The C++ DLL has some overloaded functions that use the `>>` and `<<` operators.  I've seen examples of using the %rename function for the basic operators like addition, for example:

```
%rename (____add__) *::operator +;
```

I'm wondering if there are similar function names for `>>` and `<<`, or if these operators cannot be ported to Python.  Right now I'm using

```
%ignore ::operator >>;
```

and

```
%ignore ::operator <<;
```

to get rid of the SWIG warnings but I would like to be able to port these operators if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do:

```
%rename(__lshift__) operator<<;
```

and rshift for the corresponding right shift operator, from the Python number protocol.

(Note that if you use -builtin with SWIG you'll need to use tp_slots instead of `%rename`).